# Replace @ with _at_ in URL .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following URL:

```
http://testhost.com/offers/311/133/test@test.com/
```

and I'm wanting to redirect it to this url:

```
http://testhost.com/offers/311/133/test_at_test.com/
```

Can someone provide me with the Rewrite Conditions and Rule to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^@]*)@(.*) /$1_at_$2
```

For an external redirect, add the `[R,L]` flag.

Comment: Thanks for that! Can you please explain to me what [R,L] means?

Comment: @Jesse Bunch: The *R* flag is to explicitly cause an external redirect instead of an internal. And the *L* flag (*last rule*) is to abort the rewriting process. See also [rewrite flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags).